# Z-index не работает

Tags: html, css

HTML code:

```
<div id="img">
<img src="img.jpg" id="img" />
    <div id="panel" style="display:none"></div>
</div>
```

Ставлю вот такой CSS:

```
#img {
height:234px;
width:234px;

border:1px dotted #000;
z-index:1;
}

#panel {
margin-top:-50px;
height:50px;
width:234px;

background-color:#43433f;
opacity:0.6;
z-index:2;
}

#img:hover {
display:block;
}
```

Под основной фоткой лежит черная панель. Которая должна выходить вперед при наведении мыши. Ничего не происходит. В чем причина?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cобытие мыши обрабатывается элементом `#img` - делайте наоборот, понижайте `z-index` `#img;`

Comment: спасибо! Помогло! А еще вопрос: Как сделать чтобы она появлялась при наведении мыши? Делаю так:

    <div id="panel" style="display:none"></div>

CSS:

    #panel:hover {
 display: block;
    }

Но не работает. В чем проблема? @eicto

Comment: если `display: none;` то элемента нет в поле видимости. наводить не на что. может вам подойдет opacity

Comment: Обновил код. Выложил все. Так будет понятнее Вам @eicto

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/AA4K8/

Comment: спасибо большое. Но тут одна проблема, как сделать чтобы она работала в области 234х234? Т.к щас когда в другом месте наводишь мышью, в правой части даже, она выскакивает @eicto

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/AA4K8/1/